# How to prove that $\{a\} \times \{a\} = \{\{\{a\}\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove that $\{a\} \times \{a\} = \{\{\{a\}\}\}$.

The cross product $\times$ between the sets $A$ and $B$ is defined as the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

The ordered pair $(a,b)$ is defined as $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$.

Now $\{a\} \times \{a\} = (a,a) = \{\{a\}, \{a,a\}\} = \{\{a\}\}$ only.

Can you comment on this.

Comment: Your last equality is false, for cardinal reasons.

Comment: @RobertGreen, Can you explain more.

Comment: $\{ a \} \times \{ a \}$ not same as $a \times a$.

Comment: Robert Green is mistaken;  the last equality is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\{a\}\times\{a\} = \{(a,a)\}$$

Comment: Heck, I forgot to add the set symbol around the ordered pairs.